# Page not getting redirected properly

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm only using [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and not [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

I've an English version of page set as front page( node/page1).

I've restarted working on my multilingual site after 2 months and previously it was working fine. 
Earlier I had added French, German, etc translated version of this page.

So if I go to mysite.com/de or mysite.com/fr those translated pages are shown automatically(in short existing translated pages are getting redirected correctly).

But now (after 2 months) when I add translation for untranslated languages like "it" then mysite.com/it does not redirect to the Italian version of the home page.

I've Global Redirect, Translation Redirect enabled. I've also tried clearing all cache several times.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like a bugreport to me... Have you tried to play with disabling one of your modules and seeing if others work then? Also be advised that [if you set 404](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/110651/16495), you may be deleting redirection headers, as you can have only one status header.

Comment: not using anything like 404 to this site.

Comment: I know it is stupid question, but in a case of "usually worked for me" I just have to ask it. Have you thoroughly cleared chaches after adding new language? And considered regenerating aliases, and so on?

Comment: I tried clearing all cache several times. I had already downloaded and enabled some 18 languages. So Italian was already there. Adding a new Vietnamese or Italian or so page(I mean a new node) will not redirect the site.com/it or site.com/vi to their node versions. I've restarted work in my site after 2 months and it was working fine earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be because of the "language detection" configuration.

So check this configuration via *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'.